# How to create multiple rows with just 1 different STRING_AGG column in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate

I have written an BQ SQL with a STRING_AGG(ValueId) column. I want to separate it out to multiple rows with all others columns having the same value except the column ValueId.

```
main_id   ValueId   orders
1           3,4,5     30
```

Expected

```
main_id   ValueId   orders
1           3        30
1           4        30
1           5        30
```

This above is just a sample. I have other columns than `orders` which I want to duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.* REPLACE(val AS ValueId)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(ValueId)) AS val
```

> I have other columns than orders which I want to duplicate.

As you can see, proposed solution does not require explicit mentioning of rest of the column - they all will be presented in output

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()` and `unnest()`:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as main_id, '3,4,5' as valueId, 30 as orders
     )
select t.main_id, v as valueId, t.orders
from t cross join
     unnest(split(t.valueId)) v;
```